# How to force input field value validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am writing a script that fill information to website's form and then submit it.
I enter the data to input field by `document.getElementById("input_field_id").value = "value";`; form before being submitted has to be validated by AngularJS code, but when data pops up in the field it's not validated, how can i force that?

Code sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/VuLLF7FRc3kg6gFj3EB3?p=preview
                                                                              /code is not mine, i use this as a example of my problem/

Comment: what kind of validation you want on your input fields.

Comment: in the link above app.js file contains validation code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `document.getElementById` you are executing that outside of the Angular scope, therefore your app isn't aware of these changes. You need to do it inside you controller instead, like this:

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.current.name = "asdasd";
}, 1500);
```

Comment: Please select it as the answer if it worked, thanks.